# WPF create readonly text in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I need to create some read-only text in **RichTextBox** **element**. Is it possible to do it?

- I tried to do it with **InlineUIContainer** and put there **TextBlock**, but it does not suit for me, cause in this case an user cannot apply styling for this text (make it bold or italic etc).
- Also i tried the previous variant and put **Run** into **TextBlock** and make binding between parent **Paragraph** element and **Run**, but binding does not work

code:

```
var run = new Run(key);
var inlineUiContainer = new InlineUIContainer(new TextBlock { Inlines = { run } });
var paragraph = new Paragraph(inlineUiContainer);
run.SetBinding(Run.FontSizeProperty, new Binding(nameof(Paragraph.FontSize)) { Source = paragraph, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay});
this.DocumentEditor.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

Comment: Yes, but solution from there is not suit. Unclear enough how user can apply styling for it.